# How to print out a value for a key of the first member of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need to print out the value of `"text"` where `ID = 0` in this list of dictionaries:

```
{ "ID":"0", "Text":"Once upon a time"},
{ "ID":"1", "Text":"The good end"},
{ "ID":"2", "Text":"The bad end" }
```

I can print out all of the values for the key "text" but not just an individual one with the following snippet:

```
with open ('story.json', 'r') as storyFile:
   story = json.load(storyFile)

for passage in story:
   print(passage["Text"])
```

Comment: "json" tag removed - you're working on a python list of python dicts, the fact it has been built from some json text is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `if` and specify your condition:

```
for passage in story:
    if passage["ID"] == "0":
       print(passage["Text"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to separate each object then try to print the specific key value pair.